# Build binary Ruby 2 gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

In our production environment, we are forbidden from having compilers installed (don't ask).  Back in the Ruby 1.8.7 days, we would use gem-compile to compile binary gems on a dev workstation and put the binary gem out in our repository.  Is anybody aware of any similar methods that work with Ruby 2.0?  I know RVM is capable of building custom packages of rubies that can be deployed, but I can't find any way to make it work with gems.

I'd like to come up with something a little less brittle than building everything on a dev box and rsync'ing the entire rvm directory over to the server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the answer.  There is a newer gem called gem-compiler from https://github.com/luislavena/gem-compiler that works with Ruby 2.  I didn't think it was working because I inadvertently still had an old copy of gem-compile installed and that was getting executed when I ran 'gem compile'.  Anyways, this generates platform specific gems for me that I can install in our production environment.

Cheers and Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 0):

check this part of rvm offline installation - http://rvm.io/rvm/offline#installing-gems :

### Online

1. Create a (fake) project directory: mkdir gems; cd gems
2. Install bundler: gem install bundler
3. Create Gemfile: bundle init
4. Add rails to it: echo "gem 'rails'" >> Gemfile
5. Install all gems: bundle install
6. Get gem files: bundle package
7. Package project: tar czf gems.tgz .
8. Download bundler from https://rubygems.org/gems/bundler the Download link

### Offline

1. Create a (fake) project directory: mkdir gems; cd gems
2. Unpack gems: tar xzf gems.tgz
3. Install bundler: gem install bundler-1.2.1.gem
4. Install gems: bundle install --local

Comment: Unfortunately, this just packages up the gems that came down from rubygems.  I need something that packages up the compiled C extensions along with it.  For the method described above to work, I still need gcc on the target machine.  That's what I have to get around.

Comment: you could use `bundle install --path vendor/bundler` and use `vendor/bundler` - but this might require ensuring the same system, version, architecture, paths on the installation and target system.